# HTML in table cell being escaped

Tags: theming

I'm programmatically creating a table in Drupal 8, using #type => 'table'. I'm adding some HTML to a table cell, however the output is being escaped so that the HTML is rendered as plain text, rather than as HTML.

From everything I read, it sounds like all output in twig templates are escaped by default.

I'm guessing I can override table.html.twig, but I'm guessing (hoping) there is a way to do it when defining the table, rather than overriding the template each time I want to create a new table that has HTML.

Does anyone know how to use HTML in a table cell in D8?

Comment: Try if this help [Render plain text as HTML in Drupal 8 twig](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/184261/678)

Comment: Thanks - I've already seen how I can do it by overriding the twig template, what I'm looking for though is a way to do it when defining the form, so that I don't have to create a new template override each time I want to build a table that has HTML in it. Although I may just have to do that.

Answer (score 5):

The answer (that worked for me) is to use FormattableMarkup:

use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

```
$row[] = new FormattableMarkup('<span>@somevalue</span>', ['@somevalue' => 'some value']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [inline_template](https://www.drupal.org/node/2311123) while creating Table. `inline_template` description as per documentation page:

> Provides a render element where the user supplies an in-line Twig
>   template.

Here is example from Drupal 8 user permission page. The row cell `type` is defined as `inline_template` and HTML Markup and dynamic variables are passed to it:

```
  $form['permissions'][$perm]['description'] = array(
    '#type' => 'inline_template',
    '#template' => '<div class="permission"><span class="title">{{ title }}</span>{% if description or warning %}<div class="description">{% if warning %}<em class="permission-warning">{{ warning }}</em> {% endif %}{{ description }}</div>{% endif %}</div>',
    '#context' => array(
      'title' => $perm_item['title'],
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Works for me using '#markup'.

```
$html= ['#markup' => '<div class="any_class">HTML</div>'];

$results = [
  '#type' => 'table',
  '#header' => [t('Column 1')],
  '#rows' => [
    [render($html)]
  ]
];
```

Answer (score 2):

use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;
is a great anwser however you can also do:

```
$row['myrow']['data'] = [
  '#markup' => '<h2>HELLO</h2>',
];
```

or for links you can just

```
 $row['myrow']['data']['#links'] = [
   $operations['edit'] = [
      'weight' => -5,
      'title' => $this->t('Edit Me'),
      'url' => Url::fromRoute('entity.someroute.edit', $route_parameters),
    ];
 ];
```

Do a search in your Site for all uses of "['data']["

also you can set some classes like

```
 $row['myrow']['data']['#attributes']['class'] = ['button', 'button-action', 'button--primary', 'button--small'];
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
  // Build row
  $rows[ $one_nid ] = array(
    'title' => array(
      'data' => $one_node->getTitle(),
      'class' => 'donkey',
    ),
    'price_change_today' => array(
      'data' => array(
        '#markup' => $price_change.'<span class="price-change-icon"></span>'.$price_percent_change,
      ),
      'class' => 'burro',
    ),
  );

// Return render array for table
return array(
  '#theme' => 'table',
  '#header' => $headers,
  '#rows' => $rows,
);
```

Thanks everyone for the code samples that helped me figure this out!