# How can I access raw field values in a view template?

Tags: views, theming, 8, entities

I am writing a template for a views field in Drupal 8.
How can I access the **raw values** of a multi-value field in views? I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
{% for i in 0.. row.field_color['#items']|length - 1 %}
{{ row.field_color[i] }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Try something like `{{ row.field_color[i]|raw }}`, check [example here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/184281/678).

Comment: Can you please specify which twig you are working on??

Comment: This is probably the equivalent of a raw value: `{{ row.field_color[i]|striptags }}`

Comment: I working in views-view-fields--styles.html.twig. Styles is the name of the view.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using it in views-view-fields--styles.html.twig, it would be `{{ fields.field_color.0 }}` or `{{ fields.field_color.content|striptags }}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the entity to get the raw values from the database:

```
{% for item in row._entity.field_color %}
  <p>{{ item.value }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That did not display anything.

Comment: Tested it in views-view-fields--myview.html.twig. It works. If you have a view configured on the entity the field is in, for example node. Test this with `{{ row._entity.entitytype.id }}`