# how do I access raw URL from a File Field to render it in twig inside href?

Tags: theming

I have a "Our Staff" Content Type, that includes a field for uploading an individual's CV as a PDF:

```
field_cv_file
```

I have created a View for this Content Type, then added it to page via Blocks

The twig file I'm using to render/style this area is:

```
views-view-fields--our-staff-view--block-1.html
```

I'm having trouble with the URL for the File Field

I can render it as a PDF icon link like this:

```
{{ fields.field_cv_file.content }}
```

But I want to obtain the 'raw' URL to apply inside a href, something like this:

```
<a href="{{ fields.field_cv_file.content }}">Download CV</a>
```

This however is not working.

I've tried a few different ways of rewriting the code in href, but none are working.

how would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the raw field value in a twig template?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/228388/how-do-i-get-the-raw-field-value-in-a-twig-template)

Comment: @Hudri Unfortunately no. I don't get any results when I use any {{ content.... }} code as my twig is a fields twig. Example - this shows PDF icon /link: {{ fields.field_cv_file.content }}  but changing that code to be consistent with the accepted answer that you linked to does not produce anything. I'd like to grab the 'raw' url path in order to apply it as href.

Comment: Ah, missed that part with views. For views fields take a look at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/223731/how-can-i-access-raw-field-values-in-a-view-template

Comment: @Hudri sorry they didn't work either. the accepted answer just threw a target id error on my site, and the other less popular asnwer ( 'strip tags'...) listed the PDF file name as a title like this "Name of PDF.pdf" but no actual path,

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel Change the display type option for CV file field to display as 'URL to file'. I think right now you are displaying this as a generic file that is why it appears on front as a file. I assume you are using 'file' field type for 'CV file' field. I hope my comment helps you out.

Comment: @ManishJain OK thanks Manish, and once I do that,  which if the methods mentioned throughout comments should I be using?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel didn't understand your last comment

Comment: @ManishJain what I mean is, I can render the field already, but I want to render it as a full path that I can apply as a href. I changed the file display from Generic File to File to URL to File as you suggested. I then placed it in a href like this: <a href="{{ fields.field_cv_file.content|striptags }}">LINK TEXT</a>. Unfortunately that does not work, the path is not correct and just links to a missing page

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel Yes i understand. You just need to change the display type of field in view. It will automatically render pdf path in href.

Comment: ah thank you! I thought that changing it's display within the content type would reflect in the view as well. I've now changed it in view and it's working with the 'striptags' code. I'll edit my question now to describe what the solution was. Thank you.

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel Its better if you change it's display from view only. As changing from content type would also impact on field node view.

Comment: @ManishJain Ok no problems Manish I've corrected that now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case as I was using a views twig, and required the field's file path to be usable inside a href, I had to write it like this:

```
<a href="{{ fields.field_cv_file.content|striptags }}" target="_blank">Download CV <i class="fal fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
```